# Vue 3 composition api hook vs ES6 modules import

Tags: vuejs3

is there any differences between using composition hook to inject dependencies `useRouter()` and ES6 module import `import router from './router'`

router.ts

```ts
export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    // history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
});
```

page.ts using composition hook

```ts
export default {
    setup() {
        const router = useRouter()  
        router.back()
    }
};
```

page.ts using ES6 import

```ts
import router from './router.ts'
export default {
    setup() {
        router.back()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference between Vue Router's `useRouter()` method and importing the router directly. You can see this in [the source code for `useRouter`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/master/src/useApi.ts), which is just three lines that return the router instance.